# IN, OUT, INOUT Parameters

Tags: c++

Please explain the execution of the program such that why it will generate such specific outputs.

The output is

```
6 10 20
6 10 8
2 2 14
```

My guess would have to be that it is due to the IN, OUT, INOUT parameters but I am not really understanding it

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sunny(int&, int);
void cloudy(int, int&);

int temp;

int main()
{
    int num1 = 6;
    int num2 = 10;
    temp = 20;

    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << temp << endl;

    sunny(num1, num2);
    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << temp << endl;

    cloudy(num1, num2);
    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << temp << endl;
}

void sunny(int& a, int b)
{
    int w;
    temp = (a + b) / 2;
    w = a / temp;
    b = a + w;
    a = temp - b;
}

void cloudy(int u, int& v)
{
    temp = 2 * u + v;
    v = u;
    u = v - temp;
}
```

Comment: What you're seeing in the outputs of your program are the side effects of the `sunny()` and `cloudy()` functions. If a variable is passed by reference (using pointers in this case), its value can be altered within the function and the changes will still be visible in the main program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the output is:

```
6 10 20
2 10 8
2 2 14
```

We can see the steps like this:

Sunny call:

```
temp = (6 + 10)/2 = 8
w = 6/8 = 0 //This is because w is declared int, and int(6/8) = 0
b = 6 + 0 = 10
a = 8 - 6 = 2
```

Therefore num1 is now 2, because of the reference argument, and temp is changed to 8 because its global

Cloudy call:

```
temp = 2 * 2 + 10 = 14
v = 2
u = 2 - 14 = -12 //This variable is doing nothing
```

Therefore num2 is now 2 for same reason as before and temp is 14